# im beginner in c++ i want to know how can i get the duplicate values in 2D vector

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int N{}; 
    int T {};
    cin >> N >> T;
    int col = 2 ; 
    int row = N ; 
    vector<vector<int> > v1(row, vector<int>(col, 0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) 
        {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < v1[i].size(); j++) {
            cin >> v1[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "2D vector elements..." << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < v1[i].size(); j++)
            cout << v1[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

"So this the output this from code matrix N rows and two columns what i want to is find the duplicate values in the second column , for example in first row i have [100 1 ] sec row [200 3] third [400 3] what i want do to take 100 and 400 and sum them and ignore 200 because 200 and 400 have the same value 3 so i want to take the bigger value how can i do that in 2dvector and take the sum of [100 1] [400 3]

Comment: Can you try implementing this logic yourself, first, and if you run into a problem, then you can post your attempt, and explain how the actual results differ from your expected results. You can ask for help on stackoverflow.com with a programming issue, but you have to have written the program first, nobody on stackoverflow.com will do it for you.

Comment: well i dont need the code but i need to where i can begin with it because i didnt where i can begin that it i dont need someone to write the code for me and i want to know if im correct or not to think in that way

Comment: Ok, the usual approach would be: take out a blank sheet of paper and a pen. Write down, in plain English, but using short, brief sentences, a step by step process for implementing what you want to do. When finished, [schedule an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to review your proposal. After your rubber duck approves, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished. Works every time it's tried.

Comment: oke may i ask something else                                                                                  [ for (size_t j = 0; j < v1[j].size(); j++) {
            if ( v1[j][1] != v1[j+1][1] )
            {
                total += v1[j]; 
            } this loop can work ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see for yourself if it'll work. I can tell you in advance that this will not work, and a crash is almost guaranteed. But you should try it yourself, and learn how to use your debugger to figure out the reason for the crash. It is actually very fortunate that you are a "C++ beginner", and you get an opportunity to learn how to use a debugger right up front. This is something that every C++ developer is required to know, and this is an excellent opportunity to get a head start on learning this critical skill.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems better suited to a `std::map<int, int>` because you have several pairs of things (in this case both `int`s), where you want one of the elements of the pair to maintain uniqueness among all pairs, but the other element can be duplicated. In your particular case, your second item input at each pair would be the `key` of the map, and your first item input at each pair would be the `value` associated with that key.

During insertions, you

1. Check if that `key` already exists in the map
2. If it doesn't, insert the `key`: `value` pair
3. If it does exist, compare the `value` in the map against your currently-inserting `value`
4. If the new `value` is greater, replace it, otherwise leave the old value

Then you are guaranteed to have a container with unique `keys`, where each `value` is the greatest of all `value`s inserted at that key.

Something like:

```
std::size_t number_pairs;
std::cin >> number_pairs;

std::map<int, int> max_value_map{};

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < number_pairs; i++)
{
    int key, value;
    std::cin >> value >> key; // normally we input keys before values, but this ordering mimics your current setup
    if (max_value_map.count(key) == 0)
    {
        // The key doesn't exist in this map, so the current value is guaranteed to be greatest
        max_value_map[key] = value;
    }
    else if (...check if the input value is greater than the currently mapped value...)
    {
        max_value_map[key] = value;
    }
}

...iterate through the map to add all values and output them...
```

Comment: well that seams the solution im looking for but can you give a hint over mapping because when i search on websites its confusing to understand just explanation of the braise of map in c++ and i will do the code maybe if you could use example and really thank you for your answer i really appreciate it

Comment: @jim Try this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map. It can be hard to understand at first, but there's no substitute for a good resource. Do you have a good C++ book?

Comment: i have primer c++ its the online pdf one

Comment: but my solution using vectors 2D was not going to work ?

Comment: Your solution using 2d vectors may have worked. I didn't look at it too closely. It just seems easier to use maps. Use the tool for the job. The job your doing fits into a map very nicely.

Comment: @jim What development environment are you using? Search online for "how to use X debugger C++" where X is your development environment. You *need* to learn how to use your debugger. To step through code an look at variable values at each step to make sure they are doing what you want them to do.

Comment: Oke what this line mean [max_value_map.count(key) == 0] ,  number_pairs, max_value_map{}

Comment: `std::map.count(key)` returns the number of items in a map that have that given key. Therefore, if a `key: value` pair exists in a `map`, then `count(key)` will return 1. Otherwise it will return 0. This whole if statement basically says, "If this element is not in the map"

Comment: `number_pairs` is how many inputs you want to accept from the user. This is the same as `N` in your code.

Comment: `std::map<int, int> max_value_map{}` creates a `map` with `int` type keys and `int` type values called `max_value_map` that is default initialized, i.e., created empty.

Comment: well im sorry i know im asking alot but this { https://open.kattis.com/problems/bank } what im trying to solve

Comment: @jim In that case I'd advise against simply removing lines with duplicate minute values. If your input has only three lines, `1000 10`, `1000 10`, `1000 10`, then you have 3 customers each willing to wait 10 minutes, and you can service all 3 of them in only 3 minutes. The max money you can collect is not 1000 in this case but 3000.